# How to pass ActualWidth of TextBox to Converter using TemplateBinding in WPF

Tags: wpf, ivalueconverter, templatebinding, actualwidth

I'm trying to pass `ActualWidth` of `TextBox` to `Converter` when binding using `TemplateBinding`. This is the `XAML`:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsKeyboardFocused, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" Width="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth , Converter={StaticResource FullWidthToContentWidthConverter}, ConverterParameter='10'}" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And this is the converter itself:

```
public class FullWidthToContentWidthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var fullWidth = double.Parse(value.ToString());

        var widthToSubtract = double.Parse(parameter.ToString());

        return fullWidth - widthToSubtract;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Every time I run this app `value` that comes to `FullWidthToContentWidthConverter.Convert` is equal `0`, which is not true.
I also tried to replace `ActualWidth` with `Width` then value became equal to `NaN`, which is also not the case.
How can I pass real `ActualWidth`?

Comment: Try with normal binding + templated parent. Template binding is optimized, so maybe this fails in your case.

Comment: @sTrenat I tried, no success

Comment: @sTrenat could you elaborate please, and point out the right way?
I'm trying to get the actual width of `TextBox` which this `TextBlock` is being template for.

Comment: Ok, i just realized, you'r doing this in trigger. I tried your code and it works for me. Obviously, on init it's 0, but after init, it's fire 2nd time and then it's size is ok. Are you sure this don't work for you? Can you give us more code?

Comment: @sTrenat Why is it 0 on init and is there a way to pass an actual width to converter when the form gets initialized?

Comment: Do you realy need width when ekement is not even loaded? can you see any weird behaviour on UI, or just 0 when in breakpoint? For me, you'r sample code work as expected.

Comment: @sTrenat  This is just a sample code I used to demonstrate the issue I have. In reality in this line `<TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" Width="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth , Converter={StaticResource FullWidthToContentWidthConverter}, ConverterParameter='10'}" />` I use my custom control that inherits from `TextBlock` and I need to pass `TemplateBinding` width to this element to do some operations inside my control later on.

Comment: Can you provide code, that will allow to reconstruct issue? It's realy hard to guess what's wrong when I can't see it.

Comment: It is 0 since the `TextBox` control is not rendered yet. If you pass a "default value" during the control initialization, it will be overwritten by the real `ActualWidth` value immediately after. So why do you need it?